# How to establish WebRTC call with the help of openfire xmpp or ejabberd?

Tags: android, webrtc, voip, ejabberd, openfire

I'm investigating how can I establish call with the help of webrtc by openfire or ejabberd server. I want to use one of it for signaling (change sdp, check status of call etc).
I have experience how to do it with SIP, but I haven't no Idea how I can do that with the help of XMPP.

May be someone worked with it and know where I can find information about it?

Answer (score 1):

[You can use XMPP Jingle to negotiate WebRTC calls](https://xmpp.org/uses/webrtc.html). This is an XMPP spec dedicated to VoIP.